# Upgrading Linux Mint 17.3 KDE edition to 18.2 KDE in situ

Tags: linux-mint, kde, upgrade, dist-upgrade

Officially, upgrading the KDE version of Linux Mint 17.3 to 18 is [not supported](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2316), because "Linux Mint 18 KDE will use a new and different desktop called Plasma". I presume this means that the KDE4 to KDE5 upgrade process is not trivial. The official way to upgrade is to do a clean reinstall.

I use Linux Mint on my main (scientific computing) workstation, and would much rather not do a clean reinstall: following advice, my `/home/` is not on a separate partition, I have several different (non-physical!) users installed, and the official installers just want to wipe everything and start again. I'd really much rather not.

What I'd like to do is update all of the apt sources to point at the right place, do an `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` and go home for the evening. As it stands at the moment, quite a few things randomly break every time I do an `apt-get update` (at the last one, nvidia drivers, cuda, and xfce due to a change in dbus!). I *like* the look of Plasma, and the live usb of 18.2 runs great on my computer. I *want to upgrade* *without* wiping *everything*. This is far from an unreasonable request.

I have't heard of anyone else doing this *successfully* for KDE Mint 17.3, and I'd like to know if it's possible. `mintupgrade` certainly thinks not. I'd like to try.

What happens if you just do something stupid, like `sed -i 's/trusty/rosa/' /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Do you really need to do a dist upgrade? It is probably not worth it. If you have a real need to upgrade constantly, consider using a rolling release distro (Arch ftw)

Comment: I'd really quite like to, because the relatively old kernel version is causing problems. I realise that I could probably update each package individually -- but what's that if not a distribution?

Comment: Also, I feel like saying that I didn't realise two years ago that I'd be in this position now, and that I perhaps would have gone for Arch or similar in hindsight!

Comment: A distribution has a list of supported software versions, that in some cases cannot be altered (eg system python). I don't want to seem pushy, but you are really better off with a rolling release distro, where the upgrades are seemless. Anyway the distribution-upgrade  never worked fully for me when I used ubuntu based distros

Answer (score 0):

The Mint forums say it isn't possible, I'm saying it might work.  In my experience (I upgraded 3 systems from 17.x to 17.3 then to 18.0) it works 2 out of 3 times :)

First make sure you are totally up to date on whatever 17.x release you are on.  I'll admit to NOT using the Mint update manager, but instead I use the `apt-*` utilities since I'm so used to working on Debian servers.  First become root with `sudo -i`, then update the list `apt-get update` then upgrade all the way for your current version `apt-get dist-upgrade`.  Once that is done and you've rebooted, etc. change your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` to reference the next version up.  Note when you go from 17.3 to 18.0 the `mint-extras` repository goes away, so remove the reference to it when you change your sources file.

Do not skip from 17.2 or .1 to 18.0, and do not skip from 17.3 to 18.1 or .2 ... bad juju is much more likely to happen.

Comment: Can you perhaps detail this a bit more? Have you tried this in a VM? [I might!] Is changing `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` as simple as `sed -i 's/rosa/sarah'`? What about `/etc/lsb-release` and `/etc/os-release`? What happens if I just install MATE and/or cinnamon, and then edit out the 'KDE' part of my original install, before running mintupgrade?

Comment: @Landak yup, simple `sed` on the `official-package-repositories.list` will do it, just be sure to remove/comment out the reference to the mint-extras repo.  When you change the Mint channel to `sarah` you'll need to update the Ubuntu repo references to change `trusty` to `xenial`  as well.  The `lsb-release` and `os-release` files will be updated during the update/upgrade process.  My 3 upgrades were done on live desktop systems - my home desktop (success), my home/work laptop  (success) and my work desktop (fail).  All 3 are/were set up with same software, kept in sync on updates, etc.

Comment: This does not seem to work, at least initially: after trying it in a VM, I'm left with a login screen (mintdm) which works fine, but I can't login to plasma -- an error appears saying that it could not find a QT4 dependency. Do I need to point mintdm to start the right (i.e. not kde4) version of kde? How does one do that if so?

Comment: Dunno, I did say that 2/3 succeeded.... The system that failed failed spectacularly and since my /home is a raid volume I just reinstalled since it was the quickest option.  You may need to autoremove and then perhaps reinstall kde...

Comment: definitely possible as long as you have enough time and knowledge. [People have done upgrades in far more difficult situations](https://www.theregister.com/2022/07/25/ancient_linux_install_upgraded/)